# Bash completion for nohup

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I created a `detach` script, being a wrapper around `nohup`:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/nohup "$@" &> /dev/null &
```

and I want to get bash-completion to work for this script.

I try to use `complete -c detach`, but for all arguments there is an addition from the utilities from `PATH`.

How to properly implement bash-completion for my `detach` utility?

Comment: To make completely sure: are you using this [bash-completion](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion), right?

Comment: Yes, if trust the [information on the Internet](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/bash-completion/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using [bash-completion](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion), the easiest solution is probably to ask it how `nohup` is completed<sup>1</sup>:

```bsh
$ complete -p nohup
complete -F _command nohup
```

and then apply the same completion recipe to `detach`:

```bsh
$ complete -F _command detach
```

Refer to "Where should I install my own local completions?" in bash-completion's [FAQ](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/#faq) for the most suitable place for this command.

The `_command` function in turn invokes `_command_offset`, which is, according to a [comment in `bash_completion`](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/b12639a6becec13a0a2c06173ba40fb3bbe972e1/bash_completion#L1877):

> # A meta-command completion function for commands like sudo(8), which need to
> # first complete on a command, then complete according to that command's own
> # completion definition.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Assuming an interactive `bash` shell in which `bash_completion` has been sourced. If you are using Arch Linux, as a comment of yours seemed to suggest, this is true by default for every interactive Bash session (`/etc/bash.bashrc` sources `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`).</sub>